# free(data) tries to free the wrong address

Tags: c, heap-memory, free

I have implemented a tree with the nodes looking like that:

```
typedef struct node_s {
   struct node_s *parent;
   struct node_s *left;
   struct node_s *right;
   data_t *data;
}node_t;
```

with `*data` pointing to a struct of data with a `key` which is used to sort the tree.

when I add a new node it looks like this:

```
node_t *add_Item (node_t *root){  //root is the root of the tree 

    ...

    data_t *new_data;
    new_data = calloc(1,sizeof(data_t));
    if(!new_data){
        ...    //Error handling
    }
    root = insert_Node(root, new_data);
    ... //modifying new_data

    return root;
}
```

```
node_t insert_Node(node_t *root, data_t *data){

    ...    \\tree traversing and searching

    if(root->data->key == data->key){   \\if the key is already in the tree it should be replaced
        data_t *temp_data = root->data;
        root->data = data;
        free(temp_data);  \\freeing the old data
    }

    ...

    return root;
}
```

What I don't understand is that the **`free(temp_data)`** doesn't work. Additionally the debug information doesn't make sense to me:

- `temp_data = 0x0000024C856DA950`
- `root->data = 0x0000024C856DA9D0`
- and the debug message: `HEAP[Program.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000024C856D0000, 0000024C856DA920 )`
  The address in the error message is always `0x30` smaller than `temp_data`.

Just if it helps anybody: Windows 10, Visual Studio

EDIT- minimal reproducable example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct data_s {
    long key;
}data_t;

typedef struct node_s {
    struct node_s* parent;
    struct node_s* left;
    struct node_s* right;
    data_t* data;
}node_t;


node_t* init_node(data_t* data) {
    node_t* new_node;
    if ((new_node = calloc(1, sizeof(node_t)))) {
        new_node->data = data;
        fprintf(stderr, "node created\n");
    }
    return new_node;
}

node_t* insert_node(node_t* root, data_t* data) {

    node_t* node;

    if (root) {
        if (root->data->key == data->key) {
            printf("This item alreay exists!\n%ld will be replaced!\n", data->key);
            data_t* temp_data;
            temp_data = root->data;
            root->data = data;
            free(temp_data);

        }
        else if (root->data->key > data->key) {
            node = insert_node(root->right, data);
            root->right = node;
            node->parent = root;
        }
        else {
            node = insert_node(root->left, data);
            root->left = node;
            node->parent = root;
        }

    }
    else {
        root = init_node(data);
    }
    return root;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    data_t* data;
    node_t* root = 0;

    while (1) {

        if (!(data = calloc(1, sizeof(data_t)))) {
            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        printf("What is the key for the new data?\n");
        scanf("%ld", &(data->key));
        root = insert_node(root, data);

        //there would be more editing of data afterwards
    }

    return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This seems to work but I don't know why this works and my other progam not.

Comment: Please post [mcve]. This code doesn't even seem to be correct as your `temp_data` is of type `data_t` which *seem* to be  a non-pointer type, but we have no way to know.

Comment: At a glance, I think your insert function is returning the root of the node and you are trying to free that instead of the data pointer within the node.  That seems to match up with the slight offset of the function.

Comment: @ eugene you are right it is right in the actual code

Comment: `data_t temp_data` is allocated on the stack. You can only free data allocated with `*alloc()`.

Comment: This is why [mcve] is required in *every* question asking for debug help. Please post it.

Comment: i forgot the * for *temp_data -edited it already

Comment: `//modifying new_data` comes after the call to `insert_Node()` so `data->key` == 0.

Comment: How did you initially allocate root?

Comment: @niry if root==0 it will be newly created

Comment: If you can't reproduce it with minimal code, there is a very high chance that error is somewhere else (e.g. buffer overflow elsewhere that makes this part fail)